# How to hide some paths while browsing using the XType browsefield?

Tags: widget, aem, xtype

In my component dialog, I use `browsefield` XType to enable the user to browse through the page tree and select a page:

```
<page jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" 
      fieldLabel="Page"
      name="./path" 
      xtype="browsefield" />
```

At the same time, I would like to make some pages are invisible. Suppose I have the following structure:

```
pages/
    page1/
        page1_1/
        page1_2/
```

How do I make `pages/page1/page1_2` invisible, so that nobody can select it when he browses through the page tree?

Answer (score 3):

**browsefield** is a deprecated xtype, it's replacement the [**pathfield**](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.PathField) has this feature. Pathfield has a property called **predicate** which can be used for filtering. You can create and register a custom predicate that returns false for the paths you don't want to be visible in the the dialog. The name of the custom predicate can then be passed to the config of pathfield.

You can find a detailed tutorial on this here : http://www.albertoalmagro.com/2013/05/adobe-cq5-create-predicate-pathfield.html

For more on predicates, the following links can be referred :

http://www.wemblog.com/2013/04/how-to-create-custom-query-predicate-in.html

http://labs.sixdimensions.com/blog/2013-07-10/custom-predicateevaluators-or-how-i-learned-stop-worrying-and-love/